# Get the contents between two given variable strings

Tags: bash, grep, openssl, ssl-certificate

How do I get the contents between the 2 given strings?
There is no output.

```
keyword_01=’Serial\s\+Number’;
keyword_02='Signature\s\+Algorithm';
openssl s_client -servername example.com -connect example.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text | grep -i -o -P --color=auto '(?<=$keyword_01).*(?=$keyword_02)'
```

The basic recommendations work, but when it is pieced as above, it doesn't.

```
echo "Here is a string" | grep -o -P --color=auto '(?<=Here).*(?=string)'
```

The objective here is to get the contents of SSL cert contents between 2 fields.

E.g. here, the answer would be '0e:64:c5:fb:c2:36:ad:e1:4b:17:2a:eb:41:c7:8c:b0'

Comment: Use `"(?<=$keyword_01).*?(?=$keyword_02)"`, mind the double quotes if you need to interpolate variables and a lazy `*?` quantifier if you need to extract several matches on a single line. I also assume your input string looks like `Serial +Number here Signature +Algorithm`. If you meant to match strings like `Serial Number here Signature Algorithm`, you need to use `keyword_01='Serial\s+Number'; keyword_02='Signature\s+Algorithm';` (that is, remove the escape before `+`).

Comment: @Inian It might not be a dupe of only that post, but OP needs to clarify.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It seems obvious enough for now. Will revert the close action if they provide more information

Comment: This does not work as well:
$ echo $keyword_01 ---- $keyword_02  | grep -i -o -P --color=auto "(?<=$keyword_01).*?(?=$keyword_02)"

Comment: @UrsaMajor See my top comment. What is your input like? Please share a string you need to process.

Comment: I understand `0e:64:c5:fb:c2:36:ad:e1:4b:17:2a:eb:41:c7:8c:b0` is the expected output, but what is the *input*?

Comment: See http://rextester.com/AYFG92163, does it work?

Comment: keyword1='Serial\s\+Number' 
keyword2='Signature\s\+Algorithm' 
url=example.com
url_with_port=$url:443

openssl s_client -servername $url -connect $url_with_port </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text | grep -i -o -P --color=auto '(?<=Serial).*(?=Algorithm)'

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it gets input from the url.
look at the openssl command.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, when it places with openssl, the grep does not work. I think you are close to the answer.

Comment: What is the text you pipe to `grep`? Please add it to the question. We can be "close" all the time, you know, we are "close" matching with `.*`, but to be precise, we should know what the input is like, what the pattern requirements are. Help us to help you.

Comment: You can see the input when you remove the last phase which leaves:

 openssl s_client -servername example.com -connect example.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text

Comment: No way, see http://rextester.com/MTOGRF31636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved with the builtin bash parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash  
keyword1='Serial\s\+Number'
keyword2='Signature\s\+Algorithm'

inbetween='0e:64:c5:fb:c2:36:ad:e1:4b:17:2a:eb:41:c7:8c:b0'

src="$keyword1$inbetween$keyword2"

strip_begin=${src#"$keyword1"}
strip_end=${strip_begin%"$keyword2"}

[ "$inbetween" = "$strip_end" ] && echo "It works" || echo "It doesn't work"
```

For further details, see [bash substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal).

But in order to simply retrieve the two required fields from above command output, try something like this:

```
certificate=$(openssl s_client -servername example.com -connect example.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text)

serial_number_key="Serial Number:"
serial_number=$(echo "$certificate" | awk "/$serial_number_key/ "'{ getline; print $0}' | tr -d " ")
echo "$serial_number"

signature_algorithm=$(echo "$certificate" | grep -m1 'Signature Algorithm:')
signature_algorithm=${signature_algorithm##*Signature Algorithm: }
echo "$signature_algorithm"

certificate_content=$(awk '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/ {flag=1;next;} /END CERTIFICATE/ {flag=0} flag' <(echo "$certificate"))
echo "$certificate_content"
```

The basic idea is to store the certificate in a variable; then use common Unix tools like `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `cut`, `tr` et. al. and shell builtins like parameter expansion to retrieve the individual fields.

There might be a more elegant way if you need to retrieve many more values; but the optimal solution depends on knowing more detailed requirements.

Comment: we are almost there, how does this work with:

     openssl s_client -servername $url -connect $url_with_port </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text | grep -i -o -P --color=auto '(?<=Serial).*(?=Algorithm)'

Comment: Updated my answer to match your specific problem.

Comment: yes, this works for that field. How about the other fields?
the reason why I am grep'ing between 2 fields is because they may not be in the same line. Your answer is the closest so far. I am marking this as the main reference.

As well, how do you fit in the variable, $keyword_01 into
 awk '/Serial Number:/ { getline; print $0}'

Comment: Can you change "awk '/Serial Number:/ {"
to include variable fields instead of hard coded string too?

There is a reason why my formal question is on getting between 2 tags, hence I stated to get the contents between two given variable strings, e.g. 
e.g. get the 
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

Thanks.

Comment: Using variables for pattern matching in awk is, of course, possible -- I've extended the example. It's important to get the quoting right!

Comment: How about to get the contents between  "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" ?

It is the reason why I used 2 tags. Thanks, @hnicke

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: error: "
-sh: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-sh: command substitution: line 1: `awk '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/ {flag=1;next;} /END CERTIFICATE/ {flag=0} flag' <(echo "$certificate")'

"

Comment: could you also make variables on 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE' and 'END CERTIFICATE'?

Comment: It should be:
awk '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/ {flag=1;next;} /END CERTIFICATE/ {flag=0} flag' <(echo "$certificate")

Comment: could you also make variables on 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE' and 'END CERTIFICATE'?